# Deny PUT request if condition isn't met

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm having issues denying a PUT request if the logged-in user tries to update their email address. I want to make sure the only the authorized user can only update their own email. It doesn't seem to like my  res.end()or return; How can I write my code to meet this condition before updating?

app.js

```
app.patch('/:id', (req, res) => {

if(req.body.oldEmail){

  let user = req.body.id;
  if (user.email !== req.body.oldEmail) {
      res.sendStatus(401);
  } else {
      User.update(
          {email: req.body.oldEmail},
          {email: req.body.newEmail}

      ).then(user => {
          console.log(user);
          res.json(user);
      }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

import { AuthData } from "./auth-data.model";
import { AuthDataLogin } from "./auth-data-login.model";
import { LoginService } from "./login/login.service";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AuthService {
  private isAuthenticated = false;
  private token: string;
  private tokenTimer: any;
  private userName: string;
  private authStatusListener = new Subject<boolean>();
  private userId: string;
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private loginService: LoginService
  ) {}

  getToken() {
    return this.token;
  }

  getIsAuth() {
    return this.isAuthenticated;
  }

  getUserId() {
    return this.userId;
  }
  getAuthStatusListener() {
    return this.authStatusListener.asObservable();
  }

  createUser(
    email: string,
    password: string,
    instagramName: string,
    over21: boolean,
    role: string
  ) {
    const authData: AuthData = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
      instagramName: instagramName,
      over21: over21,
      role: role,
      fullName: "Not Added Yet",
      address1: "none",
      address2: "none",
      city: "none",
      state: "none",
      zip: "none"
    };
    this.http
      .post("http://localhost:3000/api/user/signup", authData)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    const authData: AuthDataLogin = { email: email, password: password };
    this.http
      .post<{
        token: string;
        expiresIn: number;
        userId: string;
        instagramName: string;
      }>("http://localhost:3000/api/user/login", authData)
      .subscribe(response => {
        const token = response.token;
        console.log("Response");
        console.log(response);
        //    this.userName = response;
        //   console.log(this.userName);
        this.userName = response.instagramName;

        console.log(this.userName);
        this.token = token;
        if (token) {
          const expiresInDuration = response.expiresIn;
          this.setAuthTimer(expiresInDuration);
          this.isAuthenticated = true;
          this.userId = response.userId;
          this.userName = response.instagramName;
          this.authStatusListener.next(true);
          const now = new Date();
          const expirationDate = new Date(
            now.getTime() + expiresInDuration * 1000
          );
          console.log(expirationDate);
          this.saveAuthData(token, expirationDate, this.userId);
          this.router.navigate(["/"]);
          let key = "UserID";
        }
      });
  }

  autoAuthUser() {
    const authInformation = this.getAuthData();
    if (!authInformation) {
      return;
    }
    const now = new Date();
    const expiresIn = authInformation.expirationDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (expiresIn > 0) {
      this.token = authInformation.token;
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      this.userId = authInformation.userId;
      this.setAuthTimer(expiresIn / 1000);
      this.authStatusListener.next(true);
    }
  }

  logout() {
    this.token = null;
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    this.authStatusListener.next(false);
    clearTimeout(this.tokenTimer);
    this.clearAuthData();
    this.userId = null;
    //location.reload();
    this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
  }

  private setAuthTimer(duration: number) {
    //console.log("Setting timer: " + duration);
    this.tokenTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.logout();
    }, duration * 1000);
  }

  private saveAuthData(token: string, expirationDate: Date, userId: string) {
    localStorage.setItem("token", token);
    localStorage.setItem("expiration", expirationDate.toISOString());
    localStorage.setItem("userId: ", userId);
    localStorage.setItem("username", this.userName);
  }

  private clearAuthData() {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    localStorage.removeItem("expiration");
    localStorage.removeItem("userId");
    localStorage.removeItem("username");
  }

  private getAuthData() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const expirationDate = localStorage.getItem("expiration");
    const userId = localStorage.getItem("userId: ");
    if (!token || !expirationDate) {
      return;
    }
    return {
      token: token,
      expirationDate: new Date(expirationDate),
      userId: userId
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you implement authentication in your app? Using passport? Post your code about authentication

Comment: I believe the file I added above is what you're asking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple problems with your code:

1. It looks like you are updating the email address before doing the check to see if the users email is the same.
2. You should use res.sendStatus(401) instead of res.end()

Try changing your code to something like this and see if that does what you want:

```
app.put('/email/:id', (req, res) => {
    let user = // get the user first to check the email.
    if (user.email !== req.body.oldEmail) {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    } else {
        User.update(
            {email: req.body.oldEmail},
            {email: req.body.newEmail}

        ).then(user => {
            console.log(user);
            res.json(user);
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
});
```

Comment: What I don't understand is that you are trying to assign let user = before the value even exists. I'm not sure how you would evaluate before the value is grabbed from backend

Comment: Correct, you need to fetch the user from the database first to check the email and then if it satisfies your condition you can then update it.

Comment: I just got it working with a FlatMap. GET request value is being passed in now. Appreciate the help!